# Mocking django's database save

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, django-unittest

I'm trying mock out a save method call on a django models.Model.
I'm using Mock as my mocking library.

I'm testing a function in the file house_factory.py , which is located at apps.deps.house_factory.

house_factory.py:
    from apps.market.models import House

```
def create_house(location, date, price):
    house = House(id=None, date, price)
    house.save()

    # calculate some stuff and further expand the house instance
    # for example house.tag.add("some-tag")

    # save after calculations
    house.save()
```

I'd like to mock out the House model.

```
class HouseModelMock(mock.Mock):
    def save(self):
        pass
```

Testing method, is part of a unittest.TestCase class

```
  @patch('apps.deps.house_factory.House', new_callable=HouseModelMock)
  def create_house_test(self, MockedHouse):

      """ Constants """
      DAYS_FROM_TODAY = 55
      DATE = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=DAYS_FROM_TODAY)
      PRICE = 250000

    # A location is also a django module , I'm using factory_boy here for building a 'mocked' location
      location = LocationFactory.build()

      create_house(DATE, PRICE)
      MockedHouse.assert_called_with(None, DATE, PRICE)   
      MockedHouse.save.assert_called_with()
```

If I run this test I'm getting a:

call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
MemoryError

This is one of my first attempts to get serious with django and testing. So maybe I'm setting things up wrong, to mock out a database call.

Any help is appreciated,

Jonas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This is one of my first attempts to get serious with django and testing" ... you don't need to mock database saves as Django automatically [creates a test DB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#the-test-database) to run your test suite against whenever you run `python manage.py test`. Then simply assert the values stored in your DB.

Ideally [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) is used to patch own tests (and logic), rather than the default Django ones.

Tip: use an *in memory db* for unit tests, such as `sqlite` put the below in your `settings.py` file:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'sqlite3'
```

This will significantly speed up your test run.